# Using getter / setter for dynamic object properties

Tags: javascript, oop, getter-setter

I have an object called `status` where I want to keep track of any status of a class.
Beside setting various statuses I also want to keep track of how long these have been active.  Now instead of defining a second property for every status to track the time, this sounded like a job for `getter / setter`.

That's where I'm stuck. How do I make them dynamic so they trigger for each property of `status`?

```js
var Person = function(options) {
  this.name = options.name;

  var _statusChanged = {};
  var _status = {};

  // How to make this dynamic?
  var expr = "isOnfire";
  this.status = {
    get [expr]() {
      console.log(_statusChanged);
      return _status[expr];
    },
    set [expr](val) {
      _status[expr] = val;
      _statusChanged[expr] = new Date();
      return _status[expr];
    }
  };
};

var John = new Person({
  name: "John"
});

John.status.isOnfire = true;
John.status.hasPinkShirt = true;

console.log(John, John.status.isOnfire, John.status.hasPinkShirt);
```

Comment: From the computed property name (`get [expr]()`), it looks like you're using ES6. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it dynamic"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, this is ES6 and runs in latest version of Chrome. Solution doesn't have to be in this syntax though, just trying to get it to work. By "dynamic" I mean I want it to trigger for `hasPinkShirt` as well, without it being predefined.

Comment: Do you have a list of these, or could they be anything?

Comment: Could be anything, but if that is impossible I could make a list.

Comment: It's impossible without `Proxy`, for which support on the ground is very thin indeed. (And it can't be shimmed.) So right now, today, a list is the way to go. See my answer for details on `Proxy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of these, just create the getters/setters in a loop, e.g.:

```
this.status = {};
["isOnFire", "hasPinkShirt"].forEach((name) => {
  Object.defineProperty(status, name {
    get() {
      console.log(_statusChanged);
      return _status[name];
    },
    set(val) {
      _status[name] = val;
      _statusChanged[name] = new Date();
      return _status[name];
    }
  });
});
```

If they could be *anything*, then you'll want to use a [`Proxy` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-proxy-constructor). With a proxy, you can capture all gets/sets without knowing property names in advance:

```
this.status = new Proxy(_status, {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
        // handle get
        return _status[propKey];
    },
    set(target, propKey, value, receiver) {
        // handle set
        _status[propKey] = value;
        _statusChanged[propKey] = new Date();
        return true; // Tells the proxy the assignment worked
    }
});
```

(Or you might use [`Reflect.get`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.get) and [`Reflect.set`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.set), but even Firefox doesn't have them yet.)

[Here's an article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-proxies.html) going into proxies in more detail.

Here's an example, but you'll need to run it in a recent version of Firefox because [support or `Proxy` in the wild](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Proxy) is still really thin on the ground, and by their nature, you can't shim/polyfill proxies.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var _status = {};
  var _statusChanged = {};
  var status = new Proxy(_status, {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
      snippet.log(propKey + " requested");
      return _status[propKey];
    },
    set(target, propKey, value, receiver) {
      snippet.log(propKey + " set to " + value);
      _status[propKey] = value;
      _statusChanged[propKey] = new Date();
      return true; // Tells the proxy the assignment worked
    }
  });
  
  status.foo = "bar";
  snippet.log("foo = " + status.foo);

})();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Until you can use them, you'll need to make setting a status a method call, not an assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'll be going with method calls: `set: function (prop, val) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You need an object called an ECMAScript 6 `Proxy`. In Firefox, they're on by default. At one point they were implemented in Chrome under "[experimental JavaScript](http://chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony)" but they seem to have been removed temporarily; see [this ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

This code works in Firefox:

```js
var output = function(text) {
      var line = document.createElement('div');
      line.innerHTML = text;
      document.getElementById('output').appendChild(line);
  }

var Person = function(options) {
  this.name = options.name;

  var _status = {};
  var _statusChanged = {};
  
  this.status = new Proxy(_status,{
    get: function(target,property) {
      return target[property];
    },
    set: function(target,property,value) {
      _statusChanged[property] = new Date();
      output("set " + property + " to " + value + " at " + _statusChanged[property]);
      _status[property] = value;
    }
  });
  
  this.show = function(property) {
    output("Property " + property + " is " + _status[property] + " since " + _statusChanged[property]);
  }
};

var John = new Person({
  name: "John"
});

John.status.isOnfire = true;
John.status.hasPinkShirt = true;

John.show("isOnfire");
John.show("hasPinkShirt");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would work for you

http://jsfiddle.net/oksbLyqf/16/

```
var Person = function (options) {
    this.name = options.name;

    var _statusChanged = {};
    var _status = {};

    var expr = '';

    var addStatusProperty = function (prop) {
        expr = prop;

        Object.defineProperty(otherStatus, expr, {
            get: function () {
                console.log(_statusChanged);
                return _status[expr];
            },
            set: function (val) {
                _status[expr] = val;
                _statusChanged[expr] = new Date();
                return _status[expr];
            }
        });
    };

    var setStatusProperty = function (prop, val) {
        expr = prop;

        if (_status[expr]) {
            otherStatus[expr] = val;
            return _status[expr];
        } else {
            addStatusProperty(expr);
            otherStatus[expr] = val;
            return _status[expr];
        }
    };

    var getStatusProperty = function (prop) {
        expr = prop;

        return _status[expr]
    };

    this.status = {
        addProperty: addStatusProperty,
        setProperty: setStatusProperty,
        getProperty: getStatusProperty
    };

    var otherStatus = this.status;
};

var John = new Person({
    name: "John"
});

John.status.setProperty('isOnfire', true);
John.status.setProperty('hasPinkShirt', true);

console.log(John, John.status.getProperty('isOnfire'), John.status.getProperty('hasPinkShirt'));
```